# How to automatically fill, sort and conditionally format 1st day of the week according to given year and month

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-dates

[image]

How can I fill-in column `A`, make it start with the day's name according to the year in `A2` and month in `A1` and conditionally format them?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dvi7FKZwz14Taivt5fJNqDxcQGFJb1jrS5kqJdbzYXw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following formula

```
=SEQUENCE(COUNT(B5:B),1,DATE(A2,MONTH(A1&1),1),1)
```

[image]

You then format your cells as `Tue` found under `Format` >`Number` >`More date and time formats`

[image]

I also noticed that you have the following conditional formatting applied, which will no longer work

```
=OR($A5="Fri",$A5="Sat")
```

What you should now use is

```
=OR(WEEKDAY($A5)=6,WEEKDAY($A5)=7)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I really learned quickly with your tricks and ideas